# Driver problem with AMD/ATI Bonaire XT Radeon HD 7790/8770

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, radeon, fglrx

First of all sorry if I ask a dumb question, I'm new to Ubuntu. I can't find find a solution to this problem.

I tried to install drivers for Ati Radeon Hd 7xxx series, Catalyst and whatever. Everytime I did that I ended up crashing my system and finding myself with nothing.
Had to reinstall it every single time. How do I do this? I try playing 1 or 2 games and it is lagging as hell, also I've got some pretty nasty lags Everytime I try watching a video on YouTube or watching a simple movie.
Any suggestions?

Comment: How exactly did you install the drivers? If you did it from the website, do this instead. Open the Additional Drivers app (search for it) and use it to install `fglrx`, the proprietary drivers for AMD.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install the Open Source Driver.
Open up Additional Drivers by opening up a terminal and trypeing in

> /usr/bin/software-properties-gtk --open-tab=4

and then you need to click on the open source driver and then click apply.

The Open Source Driver worked really well with my ati card.